# How to run a Gradle Tomee-embedded application

Tags: gradle, jax-rs, apache-tomee

I'm new on Jakarta and I'm trying to run a simple REST application using the Tomee-embedded Gradle plugin but I'm missing something and I don't know what. The TomEE server is running but all I receive is a 404.

The task is executed by the Gradle Wrapper in version 6.9.4 (the plugin seems not being compatible with more recent versions of Gradle).

```
#gradle-wrapper.properties
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.9.4-bin.zip
```

The build script is defined as this :

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        maven {
            url 'https://build.shibboleth.net/maven/releases'
        }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'org.apache.tomee.gradle:tomee-embedded:9.1.0'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'org.apache.tomee.tomee-embedded'
apply plugin: 'war'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven {
        url 'https://build.shibboleth.net/maven/releases'
    }
}

dependencies {
    providedCompile group: 'jakarta.servlet', name: 'jakarta.servlet-api', version: '4.0.4'
    providedCompile group: 'jakarta.ws.rs', name: 'jakarta.ws.rs-api', version: '3.0.0'
}

tomeeembedded {
    tomeeVersion = '9.1.0'
    skipDefaultRepository = true
}
```

Currently, the project is resumed to only one resource class FoosResource, located in `projectRoot/src/main/java/fr/laboiteadodo` :

```java
package fr.laboiteadodo;

import jakarta.ws.rs.*;

@Path("foos")
public class FoosResource {
    @GET
    public String get() {
        return "Hello world!";
    }
}
```

As precised in the Jakarta documentation:

> If no `Application` subclass is present, JAX-RS implementations are REQUIRED to dynamically add a servlet and set its name to `jakarta.ws.rs.core.Application` [...].
>
> Additionally, the application MUST be packaged with a `web.xml` that specifies a servlet mapping for the added servlet.
>
> https://jakarta.ee/specifications/restful-ws/3.0/jakarta-restful-ws-spec-3.0.html#servlet

I have a `web.xml` file locate in `projectRoot/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF`:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
        http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>jakarta.ws.rs.core.Application</servlet-name>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>jakarta.ws.rs.core.Application</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

**First question:** What means *JAX-RS implementations are REQUIRED...* ? Am I right saying tomee-embedded is implementing JAX-RS ?

**Second question:** Is `src/main/webapp/WEB-INF` the right place for `web.xml` ?

I first build the project executing the `war` task. Until there, everything is ok.

**Third question:** Do I really need to build the project first ?

Then, I launch the TomEE server using the `tomee-embedded` task:

```plaintext
16:16:07: Executing 'tomee-embedded -i'...

The client will now receive all logging from the daemon (pid: 1810951). The daemon log file: /home/calcimicium/.gradle/daemon/6.9.4/daemon-1810951.out.log
Starting 2nd build in daemon [uptime: 3 mins 26.359 secs, performance: 99%, non-heap usage: 20% of 256 MiB]
Using 8 worker leases.
Watching the file system is disabled
Starting Build
Settings evaluated using settings file '/home/calcimicium/projects/FooBar/settings.gradle'.
Projects loaded. Root project using build file '/home/calcimicium/projects/FooBar/build.gradle'.
Included projects: [root project 'FooBar']

> Configure project :
Evaluating root project 'FooBar' using build file '/home/calcimicium/projects/FooBar/build.gradle'.
Compiling build file '/home/calcimicium/projects/FooBar/build.gradle' using SubsetScriptTransformer.
Compiling build file '/home/calcimicium/projects/FooBar/build.gradle' using BuildScriptTransformer.
All projects evaluated.
Selected primary task 'tomee-embedded' from project :
Tasks to be executed: [task ':tomee-embedded']
Tasks that were excluded: []
:tomee-embedded (Thread[Execution worker for ':',5,main]) started.

> Task :tomee-embedded
Caching disabled for task ':tomee-embedded' because:
  Build cache is disabled
Task ':tomee-embedded' is not up-to-date because:
  Task has not declared any outputs despite executing actions.
Resolving tomee-embedded classpath...
configuration key 'resource.loader' has been deprecated in favor of 'resource.loaders'
configuration key 'class.resource.loader.description' has been deprecated in favor of 'resource.loader.class.description'
configuration key 'class.resource.loader.class' has been deprecated in favor of 'resource.loader.class.class'
Starting TomEE from: /home/calcimicium/projects/FooBar/build/tomee-embedded/run
Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
Starting service [Tomcat]
Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/10.0.27]
Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
Using 'openejb.jdbc.datasource-creator=org.apache.tomee.jdbc.TomEEDataSourceCreator'
********************************************************************************
OpenEJB http://tomee.apache.org/
Startup: Mon Jul 03 16:16:08 CEST 2023
Copyright 1999-2021 (C) Apache TomEE Project, All Rights Reserved.
Version: 9.1.0
Build date: 20230606
Build time: 11:53
********************************************************************************
openejb.home = /home/calcimicium/projects/FooBar/build/tomee-embedded/run
openejb.base = /home/calcimicium/projects/FooBar/build/tomee-embedded/run
Created new singletonService org.apache.openejb.cdi.ThreadSingletonServiceImpl@23a8f18
Succeeded in installing singleton service
TomEE configuration file is '/home/calcimicium/projects/FooBar/build/tomee-embedded/run/conf/openejb.xml'
Configuring Service(id=Tomcat Security Service, type=SecurityService, provider-id=Tomcat Security Service)
Configuring Service(id=Default Transaction Manager, type=TransactionManager, provider-id=Default Transaction Manager)
Using 'openejb.system.apps=false'
Using 'openejb.deployments.classpath=false'
Creating TransactionManager(id=Default Transaction Manager)
Creating SecurityService(id=Tomcat Security Service)
Using 'openejb.servicemanager.enabled=false'
registering MBean org.apache.cxf:bus.id=openejb.cxf.bus,type=Bus,instance.id=969613458: org.apache.cxf.bus.ManagedBus@63b9d89a
registering MBean org.apache.cxf:bus.id=openejb.cxf.bus,type=Bus,instance.id=969613458: javax.management.modelmbean.RequiredModelMBean@3604ab89
registered org.apache.cxf:bus.id=openejb.cxf.bus,type=Bus,instance.id=969613458
Using 'openejb.deployments.classpath.filter.systemapps=false'
Configuring enterprise application: 
Unable to initialize agent: null
Configuring Service(id=Default Managed Container, type=Container, provider-id=Default Managed Container)
Auto-creating a container for bean .Comp5377218: Container(type=MANAGED, id=Default Managed Container)
Creating Container(id=Default Managed Container)
Using directory /tmp for stateful session passivation
Enterprise application "" loaded.
Assembling app: 
Ignoring XML Configuration for validator org.apache.bval.jsr.ConfigurationImpl
using default host: localhost
------------------------- localhost -> /
Using 'openejb.session.manager=org.apache.tomee.catalina.session.QuickSessionManager'
Unknown class loader [org.apache.tomee.gradle.embedded.classloader.FilterGradleClassLoader@107c9a7] of class [class org.apache.tomee.gradle.embedded.classloader.FilterGradleClassLoader]
Using org.apache.myfaces.ee.MyFacesContainerInitializer
At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
Deployed Application(path=)
TomEE embedded started on localhost:8080
```

**Fourth question:** What am I missing ?

Thank you by advance !